# Give users ability to track applications or notes on jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Some of the jobs on the job board allow you to apply through Stack Overflow. This means that your application is tracked through the Stack Overflow communication, which is good. Some of the jobs require application through third-party services (such as Greenhouse, etc.) or are better if applied to directly (such as an email or LinkedIn contact) These do not show up on Stack Overflow.

I'd like a way to keep track of recent job applications and somehow associate those with jobs. Ideally, I'd like to be able to take notes about jobs, too, so that I can keep the research close to job application.

From a business perspective, both of these would encourage job seekers to continue to spend more time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We're considering this for the 2017 roadmap, but deferring this until we develop more concrete plans.