# Applying to jobs - it would be nice to manage my "applications"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Where exactly is the UI to manage jobs I applied for.  I envision something like a simple grid showing the company name, the date I applied, and a status (maybe with Sent, Received, etc).

After applying for a job where am I allowed to see such a thing?  Maybe I want to cancel an application?  Maybe I'd like a visual progress bar of where we are at, some contact details, etc.  Relying on email alone is not a good user experience.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Similar to [this request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338509/give-users-ability-to-track-applications-or-notes-on-jobs), we're considering this for the 2017 roadmap. Deferring for now till we develop more concrete plans.

Comment: Donna you recursively linked back to this same question. Are you playing tennis with my head?

Comment: Ha! Only by accident :) Fixed.

Comment: I guess close mine as a duplicate